# Fetch Record ID from batch job id

Tags: apex, batch, salesforce-id, record

I have a job id for a batch apex class.I need to fetch the record ids from the job id.Is it possible to use an SOQL to fetch the record id for which the particular job id ran.
I need help on the query that is to be made to fetch the record id

Comment: That's not possible. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually i got a null exception when the batch ran.I updated the code for null handling.Now I want to test for a similar replica of the record, i need the record id and eventually the record details for which the null exception came.Is there any alternative that you can suggest?

Comment: You'll just want to write a unit test to verify behavior. If you know what you fixed, you should know how to write a test to prove what you fixed.